# MacBook Pro running FireFox 35, cannot update to 37.0.2 as update fails silently

Tags: firefox, macbook-pro

I have a macbook pro running FireFox 35. I am signed up for update notifications, and the window pops up stating FireFox 37.0.2 is available. So I install it, and in fact FireFox restarts, but FireFox > About FireFox tells me I'm still on version 35.0. Does anyone know why this might be happening, and the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tired to download the latest installer from http://getfirefox.com?

Comment: yes, that worked.  And thanks. Though I had to go through a download manually, and opt to "Replace" Firefox the older version.  I certainly hope I don't need to do that for each future upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am unsure why this happens, downloading the latest installer from http://getfirefox.com will force a reinstall. All of your bookmarks and settings will be saved.